# Getting error 'Error MSB4018 The "GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask" task failed unexpectedly.' while generating step definitions from feature file

Tags: c#, msbuild, specflow

Visual Studio:2017 C#
Specflow ver:3.4.31

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4018 The "GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Exception: Unit test Provider already set.
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.UnitTestProvider.UnitTestProviderConfiguration.UseUnitTestProvider(String unitTestProviderName)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.NUnit.Generator.SpecFlowPlugin.GeneratorPlugin.Initialize(GeneratorPluginEvents generatorPluginEvents, GeneratorPluginParameters generatorPluginParameters, UnitTestProviderConfiguration unitTestProviderConfiguration)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.GeneratorContainerBuilder.LoadPlugins(ObjectContainer container, GeneratorPluginEvents generatorPluginEvents, UnitTestProviderConfiguration unitTestProviderConfiguration, IEnumerable`1 generatorPlugins)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.GeneratorContainerBuilder.CreateContainer(SpecFlowConfigurationHolder configurationHolder, ProjectSettings projectSettings, IEnumerable`1 generatorPluginInfos, IObjectContainer parentObjectContainer)
   at SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.WrappedGeneratorContainerBuilder.BuildGeneratorContainer(SpecFlowConfigurationHolder specFlowConfigurationHolder, ProjectSettings projectSettings, IReadOnlyCollection`1 generatorPluginInfos, IObjectContainer rootObjectContainer)
   at SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTaskExecutor.Execute()
   at SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() LearningStepByStep  C:\Users\***\.nuget\packages\specflow.tools.msbuild.generation\3.4.31\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets   93
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us diagnose the issue further. Providing a stack trace without context is not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error if you have two of the following NuGet packages in your project:

- SpecRun.SpecFlow*
- SpecFlow.xUnit
- SpecFlow.NUnit
- SpecFlow.MsTest

From: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Installation/Unit-Test-Providers.html

Since SpecFlow 3 you configure which unit test runner you are using via NuGet packages. Simply remove the NuGet package for the unit test runner you don't want to use and the error will be gone.

Comment: Thank you for resolving my query Andreas Willich